# Silently reporting errors to Papertrail

Tags: node.js, heroku, papertrail-app

I'm working with a large Node.js application on Heroku, with logging maintained by Papertrail. I have a central error handling and logging function which, at the moment, just logs an error to the console, displays a generic "An error occurred!" dialog, and redirects a client to a specific page (depending on where the error occurred). But neither Papertrail nor Heroku detect this as a real error, and I don't get any sort of notifications or alerts if and when they occur.

At the moment, this is my function:

```
utilities.errorLogger = (err) => {
    console.error(err);
};
```

I've tried to throw the error, which works like below:

```
utilities.errorLogger = (err) => {
    throw new Error(err);
};
```

But then the error is displayed to the client, rather than being redirected away, leaving the end user confused. Similarly, putting the error in a try-catch block does not change anything from what I currently have (the error is logged but not picked up on by Papertrail or Heroku).

```
utilities.errorLogger = (err) => {
    try {
        throw new Error(err);
    }
    catch (err) {
         console.error(err);
    }
};
```

How can I silently throw an error for Papertrail and Heroku to pick up on and treat as an error, without needing to send the error to the client? I'd like to be able to silently handle the error and have the reporting go on in the background, rather than sending any of the error details to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding out the answer. I'm using [KeystoneJS](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone) which comes with a default error handler that I hadn't seen before; I've modified it now to just redirect people while still being able to log the error.